# PostGIS replace view crashes PostgreSQL server from ArcGIS script

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, qgis-2

I have the following script which when from ArcGIS (and a similar script from a QGIS plugin) will update a view.

Every so often (around 1 in 5 times the script is run) it causes the PostgreSQL server to 'crash' (no features show up in ArcGIS or QGIS and both will hang) and the script will fail to update the view. Restarting the PostgreSQL server resolves whatever the problem was.

```
def replace_view(self, ref_num_str):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(*connection string*)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = """CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW old_search AS
            SELECT desktop_search.gid, desktop_search.search_type, desktop_search.client,
            desktop_search.reference, desktop_search.author, desktop_search.dategis,
            desktop_search.datebm, desktop_search.property_name, desktop_search.street,
            desktop_search.town, desktop_search.city, desktop_search.county,
            desktop_search.postcode, desktop_search.searches, desktop_search.reports,
            desktop_search.geom, desktop_search.asq_lasteditedby,
            desktop_search.asq_lasteditedwhen, desktop_search.asq_lockedby,
            desktop_search.shapelength, desktop_search.shapearea
            FROM desktop_search desktop_search
            WHERE desktop_search.reference = %s::text;

            ALTER TABLE old_search
            OWNER TO postgres;
            GRANT ALL ON TABLE old_search TO postgres;
            GRANT ALL ON TABLE old_search TO "Archivists";
            GRANT ALL ON TABLE old_search TO "Geologists";"""
    data = (ref_num_str, )
    cur.execute(sql, data)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    arcpy.AddMessage("the Old_Search view has been sucessfully updated")
```

I have the following errors in my postgres log:

```
2014-02-12 11:51:59 GMT STATEMENT:  DECLARE qgisf18_120 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary(st_force_2d("geom"),'NDR'),"gid","dategis"::text FROM "public"."desktop_search" WHERE "geom" && st_makeenvelope(209586.46110484766541049,77341.20856820739572868,209797.37429537757998332,77461.20856820742483251,27700) AND st_srid("geom")=27700
2014-02-12 11:51:59 GMT ERROR:  cursor "qgisf18_120" does not exist
2014-02-12 11:51:59 GMT STATEMENT:  move absolute 0 in qgisf18_120
```

However, I am unsure if they are related to the problem but nothing else looks abnormal.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.3 and postgis 2.0.1

Is there anything in my script which may be causing this problem? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: ArcInfo license, version 10.0

Comment: That doesn't sound like a "crash" at all, it sounds like the view update is blocked on a lock. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring